# Organizations in configtx.yaml

Tags: configuration, hyperledger-fabric

I am currently automating the creation of an hypeledger fabric network. The fabric-ca-server has no affiliation when i start and then I add them one by one.

Can the orderer get the organizations somewhere else than the configtx.yaml (e.g. querying the affiliations in the fabric-ca-server) ?

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to define your organizations in the configtx.yaml file only, as it uses that file to generate the genesis blocks for your system and application channel. So whichever organizations you are using in your network that must be the part of the orderer genesis block which is generated only through configtx.yaml file.

Comment: Thanks! I will try to add to the configtx.yaml on the fly, then, when creating affiliations.

Comment: Yes, But do keep in mind if you modify anything in your configtx.yaml file then you have to update it to the whole network by updating the genesis.block.

Comment: Understood, thanks! However I have seen it is possible to add organizations after the genesis block is created. Not easy, but doable: https://medium.com/@kctheservant/add-a-new-organization-on-existing-hyperledger-fabric-network-2c9e303955b2

Comment: Yes its doable and once you understand the steps then its easy too. You can also follow this tutorial to add a new organization https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/channel_update_tutorial.html